# Cauchy sequence in practice

Tags: calculus

Let $a_n$ be a sequence.

Based on Cauchy can I say that if $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| < |a_{n+1}-a_n|$ then $a_n$ converges?
The reason behind this is that $a_{n+1}$ is just a small offset of $a_n$ and let $m=n+2$ I can say that:
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}| < |a_{n+1}-a_n|$$

Now I'm not sure how to proceed from here but I feel safe to replace the $|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ with $\epsilon$ but I don't know why I feel so safe

Comment: $a_n$ could go to infinity and it also could oscilate, for example $a_{n+1}=a_n + (-1)^{\lceil \ln n \rceil}\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

$$a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$

We have that

$$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|=\frac1{n+2}\le\frac1{n+1}=|a_{n+1}-a_n|$$

but, of course, the sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ doesn't converge *finitely*

Comment: In your example doesnt sum$1\over k$ will eventually converge? cause when n=$\infty$ then $1\over k$ is almost zero so from that point we aren't actually adding anything to the sum

Comment: No, it doesn't eventually converge. It is the well-known harmonic series, which is a used example of divergent series. Google it. And there's no such thing as $\;n=\infty\;$ . Infinity is not a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Consider $a_n=\sqrt n$, for example.